# How to combine multiples images from a sequence, using any programming language?

Tags: python, c++, png, gif, animated-gif

I'm setting up a wiki for a game, and I need to put GIFs for make the site easier to understand. But I have a problem. To make the GIFs I need to merge some images, I did it image by image manually, which is annoying. So what language can I use to automate this?

I've tried some codes with python, and I haven't had any success. The only way I can make it work was using Photoshop to combine these images.

I tried this code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
images_list = []
for i in range(1,4): #insert last number of photo
images_list.append(str(i)+'.PNG')
count = 1;

directory = "C:/Users/Windows/Desktop/BloodStoneSprites/sprites1"  
#change to directory where your photos are
ext = ".PNG"
new_file_name = "vimage-"
new_directory = "C:/Users/Windows/Desktop/BloodStoneSprites/Uniao" # 
change to path of new directory where you want your photos to be saved


for j in range(0,len(images_list),2):
name = new_file_name + str(j) + ext
two_images_list = [images_list[j],images_list[j+1]]
imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in two_images_list ]
min_img_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in imgs])[0][1]
imgs_comb = np.hstack( (np.asarray( i.resize(min_img_shape) ) for i in 
imgs ) )
imgs_comb = Image.fromarray( imgs_comb)
imgs_comb.save(new_directory+'/'+name )
count +=1
```

And here are some images I need to combine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvd8N.jpg

Comment: your code isn't valid python. What happened when you ran your code? What is the expected output? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, im in cellphone and corrector is horrible. But, when i start the code appears this: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\BloodStoneSprites\mergin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'.

and the output dont show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[The PIL library hasn't been maintained](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/imaging/). ["Pillow"](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) also identifies as `PIL`, check that it's properly installed.

As mentioned in the comments, your question isn't completely clear. That said, it looks like you're trying to write something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

images_names = [
    "C:/Users/Windows/Desktop/BloodStoneSprites/sprites1/{0!s}.PNG".format(i)
    for i in range(1,4)
  ]
images = [Image.open(file_name) for file_name in images_names]

new_name_scheme = "C:/Users/Windows/Desktop/BloodStoneSprites/Uniao/vimage-{0!s}.PNG"

for j in range(0,len(images),2):
  two_images_list = [images[j],images[j+1]]
  min_img_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size ) for i in two_images_list] )[0][1]
  imgs_comb = Image.fromarray(
    np.hstack((
      np.asarray(i.resize(min_img_shape))
      for i in two_images_list
    )))
  imgs_comb.save(new_name_scheme.format(j))
```

I make no promises that the above will actually run; you'll need to work on it.
The most important changes are removing or flattening a lot of the variables, and adding the indentations needed for your `for` loops to work.
You'll note that I'm using `'str'.format(arg)` syntax. `'str' % (arg)` would also work just fine.